# Entering frequency dependent elastomer properties in abaqus

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to enter frequency dependent viscoelastic properties for an elastomer into abaqus.  I found where to enter the properties:

Edit Material->Mechanical->Elasticity->Viscoelastic

Domain: Frequency
Frequency: Tabular

The test data that I have to enter is G* (complex) in which the real component is the shear storage modulus and the imaginary component is the loss modulus.  Using this and the Poisson ratio I can compute the complex bulk modulus, K*.  However abaqus is looking for the following test data as a function of frequency:

Omega g* real
Omega g* imag
Omega k* real
Omega k* imag

Are these the values for shear and bulk modulus or are they the Fourier transform of these quantities?